# Need to convert date_part from postgres to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, date

I have a query in the postgres :
**select date_part('week', CURRENT_DATE)**
The outcome of this query is 36.

I need to convert the same postgres query into Oracle .
How do I do this ?
I tried the below query but I am getting an outcome as 5.
**select to_number(to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'Week'))FROM DUAL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Oracle date formats:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

```
select to_char(current_date,'IW') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Will check this out !